# Cannot get role to change colours

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've got a piece of code that takes a specified role and that roles server and puts it into a list, and any roles that are in the list should change colour but well.... it doesn't.

code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True,description="Linusifies a role")
@has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def rgb(ctx, role : discord.Role):
    server = ctx.message.author.server
    if (("{}, {}").format(server, role)) in rgb_list:
        msg = "{}'s rgb is turned off :disappointed_relieved:".format(role)
        rgb_list.remove(("{}, {}").format(server, role))
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
        print (server)

    else:
        msg = "{}'s rgb has been turned on :christmas_tree:".format(role)
        rgb_list.append(("{}, {}").format(server, role))
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
        print (server)
```

and in my @client.event:

```
   async def rgb_():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed:
        print (rgb_list)
        await client.edit_role(rgb_list,colour=discord.Colour(0x1abc9c))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await client.edit_role(rgb_list,colour=discord.Colour(0x11806a))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await client.edit_role(rgb_list,colour=discord.Colour(0x2ecc71))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await client.edit_role(rgb_list,colour=discord.Colour(0x1f8b4c))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await client.edit_role(rgb_list,colour=discord.Colour(0x3498db))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await client.edit_role(rgb_list,colour=discord.Colour(0x206694))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await client.edit_role(rgb_list,colour=discord.Colour(0x9b59b6))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await client.edit_role(rgb_list,colour=discord.Colour(0x71368a))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await client.edit_role(rgb_list,colour=discord.Colour(0xe91e63))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await client.edit_role(rgb_list,colour=discord.Colour(0xad1457))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await client.edit_role(rgb_list,colour=discord.Colour(0xf1c40f))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await client.edit_role(rgb_list,colour=discord.Colour(0xc27c0e))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await client.edit_role(rgb_list,colour=discord.Colour(0xe67e22))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await client.edit_role(rgb_list,colour=discord.Colour(0xa84300))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await client.edit_role(rgb_list,colour=discord.Colour(0xe74c3c))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await client.edit_role(rgb_list,colour=discord.Colour(0x992d22))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation for [`Client.edit_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).  `edit_role` takes a `Server` and a `Role`, not a list of strings.  You should be storing your list of roles as a `list` of `Role`s.  Then you can loop over that lsit to change the colours.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True,description="Linusifies a role")
@has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def rgb(ctx, role : discord.Role):
    server = ctx.message.author.server
    if role in rgb_list:
        msg = "{}'s rgb is turned off :disappointed_relieved:".format(role.name)
        rgb_list.remove(role)
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
        print (server)

    else:
        msg = "{}'s rgb has been turned on :christmas_tree:".format(role.name)
        rgb_list.append(role)
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
        print (server)

colours = [discord.Colour(0x1abc9c), discord.Colour(0x11806a)]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    while not client.is_closed:
        for colour in colours:  # make a list of Colours
            for role in rgb_list:
                await client.edit_role(role.server, role, colour=colour)
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Like this?  

`async def rgb_():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed:
        for colour in colours: 
            [discord.Colour(0x1abc9c), discord.Colour(0x11806a), discord.Colour(0x2ecc71)]
            for role in rgb_list:
                await client.edit_role(role.server, role, colour=colour)
            await asyncio.sleep(2)`

Comment: The code should work as is. I didn't feel like making the full `colours` list, so you'll have to expand it to all the colours you want.

Comment: still doesn't change colours

Comment: Your bot doesn't have the permission to manage roles on the target server. That's not something g you can code around, you'll have to give your bot those permissions.

Comment: yeah fixed that now but it still doesn't want to change colors (well alternate between the two you gave me)

Comment: You might want to wait a little longer between colour changes. Are you seeing output in the console? Are you seeing the success message when adding roles to your list?

Comment: No I don't get a success message but they are getting added to the list because I've got it setup to print what is on rgb_list every 6 seconds

Comment: in my code everything you added untill `async def rgb_():` is in the command and the rest is under `@client.event` if that helps and I do have `client.loop.create_task(rgb_())` aswell

Comment: `client.event` won't run it, because `rgb_` isn't one of the events that discord knows about. You're better off sticking this loop in an `on_ready` event.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: @FinlayMetcalfe try now

Comment: Note that `rgb_` is now `on_ready`.  The coroutine names matter for `client.event`

Comment: have changed client loop rgn_ to `client.loop.create_task(on_ready())` but still doesn't change colour of names

Comment: Yeah so whenever I try to activate it (even though the BOTS role has administrator permissions on my test server) I end up get this:
   `raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Missing Permissions`

Comment: Is it failing on the `edit_role` line? [It looks like you can edit roles that are *less than* (and presumably not equal to) your own level of permissions.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions.manage_roles).  Can your bot manage roles with no associated permissions?

Comment: Yeah it works but how could I make it change the colour of higher roles? and you cant do #rgb again once there has been one failure

Comment: Maybe re-add the bot to your server with all permissions enabled, instead of relying on permissions of roles?  You may not be able to edit the top role of the server, I'm not sure.

Comment: Is there anyway from making the loop continue even if there is an error because if I could make it spit out that it needs to be a higher hierarchy that would be fine but it just stops the rgb code all together if something goes wrong

Comment: when I do `@on_ready.error` it spits out `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'error'`

Comment: A regular old `try/catch` in the innermost loop would be sufficent.  Though you should probably just check for those roles before adding them to the list.

Comment: is there something like `client.servers` except for roles the bot has because if I can find that out I can just bypass the whole thing of having an error message and just have the role set to the highest in the hierarchy by using `move_role`

Comment: `Server.me.roles` will be the bots roles on a particular server.

Comment: isn't working for some reason
`@client.event
async def hirac():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed:
        for server in client.servers:
            await client.move_role(server, server.me.roles, 1)
`

Comment: You're fundamentally misunderstanding what `client.event` does.  When discord.py is notified of certain things it's listening for, it checks to see if there is a registered coroutine for that event, and if so calls it.  [See the Event Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#event-reference).  If you want to write a background task, see this example: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py

Comment: Ok I understand now but how would I test if a role is higher than another role like if server.me.roles.position >= role.position sort of thing @Patrick Haugh